# No puedo descargar un modulo en python

Tags: mysql, python, pip

Puse **pip install mysql-connector-python** y me aparece: **' "pip" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.**

Uso windows 10 y tengo Wampserver64

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿ Podrías contar en qué sistema operativo trabajas y cómo estar intentando instalar el conector ? Cuanto mas detallada sea tu pregunta mejores rspuestas recibiras.

Comment: wampserver no tiene ninguna relación con python. Qué estás intentando hacer? Creo que entre más tiempo te tomes en contarnos tu problema, mejor te va a ir. Qué versión de Python tienes? Cómo la instalaste? Esas cosas...

Comment: Estoy siguiendo un curso de Python, hay una parte en la que tenemos q descargar Wampserver. Ahora estoy intentando descargar el módulo mysql. Soy un poco nuevo en el mundo de la programación

Comment: WampServer es un algo que permite tener Apache HTTP, MySQL y PHP (la documentación lo explica claramente). No contiene python. Si necesitas Python, tienes que instalarlo aparte. Seguro te dijeron instala WampServer para poder usar el MySQL que trae... pero primero debes instalar python y LUEGO ponerle el módulo que **conecta** programas python con la base de datos MySQL.